# A concrete design case in C++, embedded AVR project

Tags: c++, oop

I have a design problem I pictured on a diagram below. There is a class `Owner` holding pointers to classes `Switcher` and `Base`. `Switcher` has a method, say `Switcher::switch(Base* base)` whose goal is to change `Owner::Base`'s implementation from `Child1` to `Child2` or back if needed. I wouldn't like to implement this functionality in `Owner`, as it is complex enough already. The variables `Switcher* Owner::switcher` and `Base* Owner::base` are private in `Owner`.

Is there a design pattern for this? How would should I implement it? If written some simple code to implement it but I guess I'm having problems with access control, as `switcher` and `base` member variables are declared private. I can't tell for sure, as I cannot step-by-step debug the system (it's an embedded project). I'm also trying to implement it with linux-gcc to test what's wrong, but maybe there is a simple solution I I didn't think of, and hence the question here. I wouldn't like to use friend keyword, as I somehow have a feeling using it is a sign of bad design.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why not access the base through switcher. That way, switcher can change base and owner will only see itself accessing the switch.

Otherwise, have switcher call a `setbase(Base*)` method in owner. The switching logic could then be handled in the switcher, but the access to the fields is in owner, where it belongs.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I considered calling `Base::setBase(Base*)` from `Switcher` for a short while now and `Switcher` would have to hold reference to `Owner`, than, which I don't like. I guess this idea of moving switching logic away from Owner is problematic. I also wouldn't like to move responsibility for the `Base`object itself away. So I guess I'll have to give up on `Switcher`.

Comment: What about the `Base *Switcher::getBase()` idea?

Comment: You mean moving responsibility for `Base` from `Owner` to `Switcher`? If so, I wouldn't like that. The `Base` class is just one piece in a processing chain, so there are more `Base`-alike classes which all are being created by `Owner`, so going this way I'd have to move them all to respective `Switcher` classes to stay consistent. And this would mean too much of a change.

Comment: You either need Owner to ask Switcher which base to use, or Switcher to set Owner's base. How else could Owner figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

just to gain a bit of clarity, are child1 and child2 inherited from base? If so, how are you intending to "switch" them?

Im guessing your trying to avoid circular references?

EDIT: I don't think there is a design pattern that really matches up nicely to this problem, the closest I can think of, is maybe adapting the factory somewhat so that you can hand the base back, and ask for it in a different form.

Comment: Yes, `Child1` and `Child2` both inherit from `Base`. I defined a conversion constructor between subclasses of `Base`, see the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765239/polymorphic-copy-constructor-with-type-conversion). I'm (or rather was, because I see it's no good design) just trying to lighten `Owner`'s load.